# Send data form C# to Visual Basic API

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, api-design

I have a API in C# and another one in Visual Basic. I need to send some information in JSON format from the API in C# to the API in Visual Basic, hopefully using POST verb. The context of the situation is like this. A mobile application send information to the API in C#, the API save the data in a database located in the server, then if the information is correct the API in C# have to send the data to the Visual Basic API and save it in other server. Anybody knows hoy to send the data from C# to Visual Basic? Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I dont find the way to send the data from C# to Visual Basic. If have been using WebRequest library but only works if I use GET and add the parameters to the url, if I use POST it doesnt work

Comment: Why involve VBA code at all? Just save it to both servers in whatever format it need to be on each.

Comment: C# and VB (assuming .NET) both compile to IL code - as far as the CLR cares, they're exactly one and the same. Heck, you can even compile C# and VB projects in the same solution, and reference one in the other. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter that one API is in C# and the other in VB. As long as the json you are sending is valid (try validating the json you send at jsonlint.com) and can be mapped to an object the API accepts everything should be fine.
It seems like the endpoint api is not accepting the request.

Answer (score 0):

This is my C# code

```
try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    var1 = "example1",
                    var2 = "example2"
                });

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Respuesta = result }, "application/json");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new { Respuesta = e.ToString() }, "application/json");
        }
    }
```

And this is my function in Visual Basic

```
Public Function PostValue(ByVal json as String)
    return json
End Function
```

Thats all. And throw me this error
{
  "Respuesta": "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   at Servicios.Controllers.SAPEnviarFacturasController.SAPEnviarFacturas() in C:\TFS\Servicios\Controllers\SAPEnviarFacturasController.cs:line 44"
}